# How to Change Site Name in Suit Bar Navigation of Hub Site Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, sharepoint-online, navigationbar

Hope you guys are doing best, I need some help. Actually want to change site name in top navigation bar(Suit Bar) on SharePoint Hub Site. Can you please guide me how i can do this?

Screenshot is Attached below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Select Settings[image].
- Select Hub site settings.

[image]

- Make your edits and Save your changes.